# Dialogflowで好感度設定のようなものは出来るのでしょうか

Tags: dialogflow

Dialogflowで好感度設定のようなものは出来るのでしょうか
同じキーワードを言われたとしても、
・話しかけてきた人
・好感度
などによって対応を変えたいと思っています。
何度も話しかけたらウザがったりとか。

好感度の設定みたいなものは特に無さそうだと思ったのですが
そういったことは可能なのでしょうか。
「好感度」とかで調べてみましたが、特にありませんでした。
Fulfillmentのところを編集すれば出来るのでしょうか。

Comment: 参考までに、[感情分析](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/sentiment?hl=ja) は存在するようですが、"Enterprise Edition" が必要だそうです。

Comment: cubick♦様　調べて頂きありがとうございます。「人が言った内容について考える」のではなく「AIに感情(好感度)を持たせたい」ということなのですが感情分析というのはそういうことなのでしょうか？個人利用ですし使えはしないのですが…。